# Angular 2 - Parsing JSON to class with computed properties

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to convert a JSON object which comes back as a usable TypeScript class which also has computed properties.

When mapping it gets all the returned values correctly, but removes / ignores the computed properties that should also be on the object whether I have a default value on them or not.

The desired result is that ShowPanel defaults to true

```
export class Maintenance {
  Id?: number;
  Name?: string;

  // computed property - doesn't exist on returned data as it's a client 
  // property in an ngFor loop.
  ShowPanel: boolean = true;
}

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss']
})
export class HomeComponent {
   ngOnInit(){
      this.http.get('lookup/getstatusinformation')
               .map(res => <Maintenance[]>res.json())
               .subscribe(res => this.listMaintenance = res);

   }
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that res.json() will only return a string in JSON format. You can map that to POJOs by means of an interface, but if you want to create an array of class instances, you need to loop the .json() return and instance new objects by using the constructor method of the class

Comment: @Jota.Toledo author cast json data as array of Maintenance type in .map function

Comment: TypeScript does not cast anything. You are *asserting* that the return value from `json()` is a `Maintenance` instance when it is not. It's just an object. If you want a `Maintenance` instance you will have to create one using `new`, etc.

Comment: @YD1m that means nothing, the plain objects are still not an instance of Maintenance. For example, if Maintenance had a foo() method, you cant call it from one of the objects returned by the service. Doing direct casting in the component method is kinda dumb, the best thing would be to declare the return type on the service method

Comment: @Jota.Toledo ok, you are right. Thank you for detailed description.

Answer (score 1):

When the JSON has deserialized, any properties not provided in the JSON data will be set on the target object to their default value - as if that default value was part of the response.

Personally, I iterate through the objects after creation and reset computed values.